# Artin 4.5: Prove every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, by working with exponents, and use the description of the subgroups of $\Bbb Z^+$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

> Prove that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Do this by working with exponents, and use the description of the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

My first thought on this problem is that if $G = \langle a \rangle$ is cyclic, then this is by definition the smallest subgroup containing $a$, so by definition, if a subgroup $H \subset G$ contains $a$, then $H = G$. Is that correct? So a subgroup will contain powers of $a$, but not necessarily $a$ itself.

Here is my attempt.

> Let $G$ be cyclic generated by $a$, and $H \subset G$ a subgroup. Define $S = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a^n \in H\}$. I claim that $S \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup. If $n,m \in S$, then we have $a^n a^m = a^{n+m} \in H$ by closure, so $n+m \in S$. $a^0 = e \in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup. If $a^n \in H$, then $\left(a^n\right)^{-1} = a^{-n} \in S$ since $-n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So $S$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, so we have $S = \mathbb{Z} b$ for some $b \geq 0$, as all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of this form. If $S = \{0\}$, then only $a^0 \in H$ and $H$ is the trivial subgroup, which is certainly cyclic. Suppose $S \neq \{0\}$, then $S = \mathbb{Z} b$ for some $b > 0$ and $H$ is non-trivial. Furthermore, $a^n \in H$ if and only if $n = kb$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. That is,
> $$H = \{a^{kb} \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{(a^b)^k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \langle a^b \rangle.$$
> So $H$ is cyclic, generated by $a^b$.

How does this look? I think I could shorten the argument by not distinguishing whether $S$ is trivial because it doesn't quite matter. If $S$ is trivial, $S = 0 \mathbb{Z}$, so any $a^n \in H$ is still of the form $a^{k \cdot 0}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is the identity for all $k$.

How does this look?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct that I can exclude ruling out that $S$ is trivial?

Comment: i like it.  And, how does one prove the fact about $\mathbb Z$, which you are using?

Comment: It doesn't hurt to leave it in. I guess you can remove it.

Comment: @ChrisCuster: The way I would prove it is: if $H \subset \mathbb{Z}$ a subgroup is trivial, $H = 0 \mathbb{Z}$. If not, it contains $a > 0$ (taking inverses, if needed) so it has a least element $b$. Given $h \in H$, the division algorithm gives $h = bq + r$ for $0 \leq r < b$. then $r = h - (bq) \in H$, so $r = 0$ (since $b$ is the least positive element). That gives $H \subset b\mathbb{Z}$. $b\mathbb{Z} \subset H$ is true for any $b \geq 0$, so $H = b\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: nice job @JeremyS

Comment: Looks good, but you have a little typo where you say that $a^{-n} \in S$ but you really mean $a^{-n} \in H$ implying $-n \in S$

Comment: I think that the key point is just to prove that $S=\Bbb Zb$ for some $b$, which you take for granted.

Comment: I had missed your comment above. Maybe it worths including it in the post.